# How to mouse hover this button to open a menu instead of clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this kinda animated button that opens a menu on click, 
Is it possible to mouse hover the button to open it, instead of clicking?

I'm not sure if it's with css or javascript, but here's the [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/pedrovil/gtbxpmej/2/) with the button i want to mouse hover.

Thanks in advance!

**Javascript**

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var colors = '';
    var server_url = ''; 
    var folder_url = 'colors/'; 

    // Style switcher
    $(".hide-color").show(1000);
    $('#custumize-style').animate({
        left: '-134px'
    });

    $('#custumize-style .switcher').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var div = $('#custumize-style');
        if (div.css('left') === '-134px') {
            $('#custumize-style').animate({
                left: '0px'
            });

            // open switcher and add class open
            $(this).addClass('open');
            $(this).removeClass('closed');

        } else {
            $('#custumize-style').animate({
                left: '-134px'
            });

            // close switcher and add closed
            $(this).addClass('closed');
            $(this).removeClass('open');
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Please look into this fiddle if it works as per your requirement :
https://jsfiddle.net/rawatdeepesh/gtbxpmej/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for .hover()

Leaving your .switcher class in your selector will give you some strange behavior because you would be firing your hover on the child a tag inside of your div. Removing that class fires your hover method on the parent div (your menu slider).

Line 13 of your JavaScript like this would give the behavior described above:

```
$('#custumize-style .switcher').hover(function(e) {
```

Try something like this instead:

```
$('#custumize-style').hover(function(e) {
```